# ngIf valor vacío firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, javascript-objeto

¿Cómo mostrar y ocultar un texto si el valor de entrada está vacío o no (No es necesario utilizar métodos de formulario, grupo, control ...)?

```
<ion-input type="text" id="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"  placeholder="{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}" required></ion-input>
<ion-text *ngIf="user?.email" color="primary">email invalid</ion-text>
```

***ngIf="user?.email" not working**

Comment: Saludos. Mi sugerencias es que siempre asignes un valor por default o de inicialización a cada propiedad; evita en lo posible usar obtejos null por que entonces tienes que hacer mas consideraciones al momento de evaluar una condición ya que primero (entre otras cosas) tendrías que saber si es null y que aplica en tal caso).

Comment: @robertoleor Un ej de como asignar "en este caso" un valor por defecto, gracias.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. En donde tienes declaro `user` (que usas en `ngIf` que seguro es el mismo que usas en `ngModel`) allí crear el objeto, de tal forma que sea un objeto ejm 'user=new ObjetoUsuario()`; esto acorde al tipo de objeto que corresponde y atendiendo (si los requiere) parámetros para el constructor; así mismo cada propiedad ponerle un valor explícito en el mismo constructor de la clase. Así por ejemplo "sabrás" que `user.mail` es cadena "vacia" cuando es nuevo.

Comment: @robertoleor  user: User = new User(); on .ts llamándolo de auth.service

Comment: He solventado esto haciéndolo con el form de grupo e iniciándolo desde el principio del componente. Gracias a todos igualmente.